# SQL Track proper work flow usage

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this problem I have to figure out hopefully I can explain it effectively.

- Order of operation for *Event* is: Start → Communicating → Sale Complete
- Order of operation for *Status* is: Working → Complete

I need to make sure every User is following the process and not skipping steps

So like in this example:

[image: Table Example]

- Bobo is working with two clients

  - the first Client he is still in the communicating phase but he is following t he process for the order of operations
  - but on his second client he did not complete the status for Start before moving on to Communicating.
- Mike went from Start event in Working status to Communicating Event in Complete status to Sale Complete event in Working status. So Mike is not following the order of operations either.

Obviously on a super small scale like this it only requires a small look at this to see that. Unfortunately we have 100's of users and thousands of customers at any given time that they would be working with.

I only need a count of Customer ID's where the process is not being followed (not an issue where they just are not completed with the full process just where there have been steps missed.)
and the User Name working with that client

So I guess the results would look something like

```
Bobo     1
Mike     1
```

meaning Bobo has 1 account he is working on that he skipped steps 
the same with Mike.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want to do with your table structure.  In SQL, tables are inherently unordered.  You have no way of knowing what happened first and second.

Without that information, it is impossible to determine the sequences.

Do you have an id or datetime that orders the rows?

With such a field, you can get the next status as:

```
select t.*,
       lead(EVENT) over (partition by username, customerid order by thedatetime) as nextEvent,
       lead(status) over (partition by username, customerid order by thedatetime) as nextStatus
from t
```

Next, you can just use your logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(EVENT) over (partition by username, customerid order by thedatetime) as nextEvent,
             lead(status) over (partition by username, customerid order by thedatetime) as nextStatus
      from t
     ) t
where not (event = 'Start' and coalesce(nextEvent, 'Communicating') = 'Communicating' or
           event = 'Communicating' and coalesce(nextEvent, 'Sale Complete') = 'Sale Complete' or
           event = 'Sale Complete' and nextEvent is not null or
           status = 'Working' and coalesce(nextstatus, 'Complete') = 'Complete' or
           status = 'Complete' and nextstatus is not null
          )
```

This gives all information.  If you just want customerIds, then use:

```
select distinct CustomerId
```

Comment: Actually there is a datetime field I did not add into this example but it is in the actual table

Comment: @scripter78 you should edit your question to include that. While you're at it you might want to look at [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) and use that instead of an image since it makes it much easier to copy and paste your data into something like SQL Fiddle's Text to DDL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach or similar logic, if the stages in your application are defined in a  very strict order and you can have a reference table as below.

```
with t2 as
(
select 1 id, 'start'            event from dual union all
select 2 id, 'communicating'    event from dual union all
select 3 id, 'salecomplete'     event from dual
)
select * from t2;

        ID EVENT
---------- -------------
         1 start
         2 communicating
         3 salecomplete
```

You can get the order_id/workflow_id in your data and then check if there is any other workflow item that ***should have*** preceded this item, but does not.

Eg. Check "complete" events where there is no "communicating". (or)
    Check "communicating" events where there is no "Start" event.

Here is the code. I have only included till the customer Id level, but extending it to the user who is dealing with a particular customer is fairly straight-forward.

```
with t1 as  (
  select 100 cust, 'start'          event from dual union all
  select 100 cust, 'salecomplete'   event from dual union all
  select 200 cust, 'communicating'  event from dual union all
  select 200 cust, 'salecomplete'   event from dual union all
  select 300 cust, 'salecomplete'   event from dual union all
  select 400 cust, 'start'          event from dual union all
  select 400 cust, 'communicating'  event from dual union all
  select 400 cust, 'salecomplete'   event from dual
),
t2 as
(
select 1 id, 'start'            event from dual union all
select 2 id, 'communicating'    event from dual union all
select 3 id, 'salecomplete'     event from dual
),
t3 as
(
select t1.cust, t2.*
  from t1, t2
  where t1.event = t2.event
)
select * from t3 tgt
where tgt.id <> 1 --initial event can exist by itself
  and not exists (
   select 1
     from t3 src
     where tgt.cust = src.cust
       and tgt.id -1 = src.id
);
```

This will show all the events where the preceding event is missing.

```
      CUST         ID EVENT
---------- ---------- -------------
       100          3 salecomplete
       200          2 communicating
       300          3 salecomplete
```

To get a list of customers where this is happening, just use dist cust on the last query..

```
...
      CUST
----------
       100
       200
       300
```